# Mapping to legacy MongoDB store

Tags: mongodb, yesod

I'm attempting to write up a Yesod app as a replacement for a Ruby JSON service that uses MongoDB on the backend and I'm running into some snags.

1. the sql=foobar syntax in the models file does not seem too affect which collection Persistent.MongoDB uses. How can I change that?
2. is there a way to easily configure mongodb (preferably through the yaml file) to be explicitly read only? I'd take more comfort deploying this knowing that there was no possible way the app could overwrite or damage production data.
3. Is there any way I can get Persistent.MongoDB to ignore fields it doesn't know about? This service only needs a fraction of the fields in the collection in question. In order to keep the code as simple as possible, I'd really like to just map to the fields I care about and have Yesod ignore everything else. Instead it complains that the fields don't match.
4. How does one go about defining instances for models, such as ToJSON. I'd like to customize how that JSON gets rendered but I get the following error:

> Handler/ProductStat.hs:8:10:
>   Illegal instance declaration for `ToJSON Product'
>   (All instance types must be of the form (T t1 ... tn)
>   where T is not a synonym.
>   Use -XTypeSynonymInstances if you want to disable this.)
>   In the instance declaration for`ToJSON Product'

Answer (score 1):

1) seems that sql= is not hooked up to mongo. Since sql is already doing this it shouldn't be difficult for Mongo.

2) you can change the function that runs the queries
in persistent/persistent-mongoDB/Database/Persist there is a runPool function of PersistConfig. That gets used in yesod-defaults. We should probably change the loadConfig function to check a readOnly setting

3) I am ok with changing the reorder function to allow for ignoring, although in the future (if MongoDB returns everything in ordeR) that may have performance implications, so ideally you would list the ignored columns.

4) This shouldn't require changes to Persistent. Did you try turning on TypeSynonymInstances ?

I have several other Yesod/Persistent priorities to attend to before these changes- please roll up your sleeves and let me know what help you need making them. I can change 2 & 3  myself fairly soon if you are committed to testing them.

Comment: 1 seems pretty isolated so maybe I can do that. I'd be glad to help out but I fear that I might not be much use. This is my first Yesod  app and I am entirely unfamiliar with Yesod's codebase and I'm still learning Haskell.

I'll try your suggestion on #4. Also I could probably help test as well. If we could find a medium that is more conductive to working on this (IRC/Email) I'd be glad to help in whatever way I could.

Comment: You can create github issues for 1-3. I am often on the #yesod IRC channel as gweber